# redirect/ forward in Spring WebFlow to subdomain

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow-2

I have a Java Spring Webflow application and it need to redirect to it's own sub domain for language choice. i.e. mysite.com to fr.mysite.com.

I have tried externalRedirect, but just shows a blank html page.

Here is the webflow defenition snippet:

```
<transition on="found" to="redirectOnRetrieve">         
    <evaluate expression="retrieveController.getFoundApplicationRedirect(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.redirectUrl"/> 
</transition>
```

Which determines the URL I need to redirect to. And the following is the view state with the externalRedirect:

```
<view-state id="redirectOnRetrieve" view="externalRedirect:${flowScope.redirectUrl}"/>
```

Is it also possible to append request parameters to the URL?

Comment: can't you append them to `flowScope.redirectUrl`?

Comment: For some reason I couldn't.  If I tried an externalRedirect from within the flow definition it never worked.  No error given and would stay on the same page, with no redirect done.  I did find a way though and will post that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I was after.  Doing a redirect to a subdomain within a webflow.  So this is how I managed to get it working.

So in the flow definition I have:

```
<transition on="found" to="redirectOnRetrieve">         
    <evaluate expression="retrieveController.brokerApplicationRedirect(flowRequestContext)"/> 
</transition>
```

Now, I did the redirect with in the retrieveController:

```
   public void brokerApplicationRedirect(RequestContext context) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String urlString = "http://sub.domain.com?param=myparam";        
        context.getExternalContext().requestExternalRedirect(urlString);
    }
```

So I build up the Url string any way I want then did the redirect within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Within flow.xml, the correct EL syntax is `#{flowScope.redirectUrl}` rather than `${flowScope.redirectUrl}`.